# Illegal mix of collations in mySQL

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I need to transfer a column from one table to another. The source table has a different collation than the target table (latin1_general_ci and latin1_swedish_ci).

I use

```
UPDATE target 
LEFT JOIN source ON target.artnr = source.artnr 
SET target.barcode = source.barcode
```

I get an "illegal mix of collations".

What is a quick fix to get this working without having to change either table? I tried CONVERT and COLLATE to run the whole operation in UTF-8, but that didn't help. "barcode" contains numeric data only (even though they all are VARCHARs), so there are no collation worries either way. I need to do this just once.

> Edit: I sorted it using a `CAST(fieldname as unsigned)` on every field involved. I was able to do that in this case because only numeric data was affected, but it would be nice to know a more general approach to this, so I am leaving the question open.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> I tried CONVERT and COLLATE to run the whole operation in UTF-8, but that didn't help.

It bugged me, so today I created those tables and successfully ran this one:

```
UPDATE target
LEFT JOIN  source ON( target.artnr = source.artnr COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci )
SET target.barcode = source.barcode
```

Answer (score 2):

How about joining on select with only 2 numerical columns?

```
UPDATE target
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        artnr COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci AS artnr,
        barcode COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci AS barcode
     FROM source
    ) source ON target.artnr = source.artnr
SET target.barcode = source.barcode
```

Comment: Cheers, clever idea, but both artnr and barcode are varchars even though they contain only numeric data, so even they alone will cause the problem. I'll emphasize that in my question.

Comment: Check my updated answer, only thing changed is to add collation in subselect for each column (and alias proper alias after it)