# UTF8 issue with Illegal mix of collations

Tags: php, mysql

Really hope someone can advise.

Just moved the database to Amazon RDS. Part of the move was to update the database to utf8 which went well.

I have a query which is giving me an error which is.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (`specialdaterange`)
WHERE
    `parkinglotsproduct_id` = 769
AND '02/15/2014' >= `from`
AND '02/15/2014' <= `to`
LIMIT 1
```

Error:

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '>='
```

Now none of that data is text form but as you can se[image]

Also I have made sure the parameters are correct on RDS: [image]

Im not sure where the latin1_swedish_ci is coming from?

Really hope you can advise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Illegal mix of collations in mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327778/illegal-mix-of-collations-in-mysql)

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should use date as this format yyyy-mm-dd .

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (`specialdaterange`)
WHERE
    `parkinglotsproduct_id` = 769
AND '2014-02-15' >= `from`
AND '2014-02-15' <= `to`
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yea now feel dumb.  But crazy how tah has not sown up before !!